# Running 32 bit address space code on Mac M1 chip

Tags: macos, memory-address, 32-bit, apple-m1

Prior to Apple releasing M1 Macs, you could run 32 bit address space code (using 4 byte pointers) on 64 bit Macs by using the pagezero_size option to place the code below the default start point of 4Gb. E.g. for a Hello World program:

```
c++ hello.cpp -o hello -pagezero_size 0x400000
```

Running otool -l hello confirms that the code starts at 0x400000.

If you try to do this on an M1 Mac, when you run the executable you get:

```
zsh: killed     ./hello
```

When run under lldb you get:

```
error: Malformed Mach-o file
```

So it looks like it is not possible execute 32 bit address space code on an M1 chip using the pagezero_size option. Does anyone know any other way of getting this to work, or is it no longer possible?